# How to create Custom Analyzer in Lucene, with custom stop/common words from file

Tags: java, lucene, analyzer

I m trying to create a custom analyzer in Lucene 8.3.0 that uses stemming and filters the given text using custom stop words from a file. 
To be more clear, I don't want to use the default stop words filter and add some words on it, I want to filter using only a set of stop words from a stopWords.txt file.
How can I do this?

This is what I have written until now, but I am not sure if it is right

```
public class MyAnalyzer extends Analyzer{
    //public class MyAnalyzer extends Analyzer {
    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName) {
       // public TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
        Tokenizer tokenizer = new StandardTokenizer();
        TokenStream tokenStream = new StandardFilter(tokenizer);
        tokenStream = new LowerCaseFilter(tokenStream);
        tokenStream = new StopFilter(tokenStream,StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET);
        //Adding Porter Stemming filtering
        tokenStream = new PorterStemFilter(tokenStream);
        //return tokenStream;
        return new TokenStreamComponents(tokenizer, tokenStream);
    }
}
```

First of all I am not sure if the structure is correct and for now I am using the StopFilter from StopAnalyzer just to test it (however it's not working).

Comment: Can you provide some code for what you have already tried.

Comment: This is what i have written.What I need hower is the Analyzer to return just a processed tokenstream. I read the Lucene documentation but I got confused

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the file and parse it to a CharArraySet to pass into the filter. [`StopFilter`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/StopFilter.html) has some built in methods you can use to convert a List of Strings to a CharArraySet, like:

```
...
CharArraySet stopset = StopFilter.makeStopSet(myStopwordList);
tokenStream = new StopFilter(tokenStream, stopset);
...
```

It's listed as *for internal purposes*, so fair warning about relying on this class, but if you don't want to have to handle parsing your file to a list, you could use [`WordListLoader`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/WordlistLoader.html) to parse your stopword file into a CharArraySet, something like:

```
...
CharArraySet stopset = WordlistLoader.getWordSet(myStopfileReader);
tokenStream = new StopFilter(tokenStream, stopset);
...
```